# React Native TextInput: hitting space does not change keyboard back to default from the numbers-and-punctuation keyboard on IOS

Tags: react-native, keyboard, textinput

I'm using a simple TextInput component to capture user input. When the user switches to the numbers-and-punctuation keyboard and hits space, the keyboard does not switch back to the default keyboard on IOS.

Here is an example. [code snack](https://snack.expo.dev/-Mf9lB56H):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState('')

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput style={styles.input} value={inputVal} onChangeText={text => setInputVal(text)} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[Here is a video of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCTNj.jpg) After hitting the space button on the numbers keyboard IOS I would like it to change back to the character keyboard.

I've found that adding multiline={true} to the TextInput will partially solve my problem, but for my application, it would be best if the input was not multiline. Is there any other way I could achieve the keyboard switch or am I missing something?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it. I accessed your code snack, I changed to the number keyboard but I could get back to the "letter" keyboard. Can you post a gif here showing your problem?

Comment: To be clear, I can access the letter keyboard after switching to the number keyboard, but I would like it to automatically switch back to the letter keyboard after pressing 'space'. I think It's standard functionality on IOS, but it's not working for me with a non-multi-line TextInput. I edited my post to add a video example.

Comment: Do you have an app that the iOS keyboard works like this? To be honest, I never saw this functionality.

Comment: Works on most of the apps I use (iMessage, Instagram, Twitter, GitHub app, Notes app etc...) [Here's an example of what I'm talking about](https://imgur.com/a/ZEqEH7S)

Comment: Aaaah I never noticed this behavior. You could get the input that the user typed and check if it's a "whitespace" and if the keyboard is numeric, if it's whitespace and the keyboard is numeric you change the keyboard type to the "letter" keyboard again. I don't how we could do this without a complex logic.